# Stripe subscription add-on's & features

Tags: node.js, payment, stripe-payments

Right now I have 3 types of subscriptions at my site:

- Starter (10$)
- Plus (15$)
- Premium (19$)

Also, I have a few add-on's that user can add to their subscription, e.g.:

Subscription: plus

- +feature 1(+10 $)
- +feature 2(+10 $)

Total = 15$ + 10$ + 10$ = 35$.

Users should be able to add/remove features during their billing period or switch to another plan.

How should I manage those features using Stripe?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions should give you a good understanding of what you can/can't do with Stripe's subscriptions

Comment: Basically I can do it in multiple ways, create subscription for each plan + feature(s) and switch between them, or create multiple subscription for each user. Maybe anyone know another way to do it properly.

Comment: @vromanch Did you ever find a way of doing this? Without having to create a matrix of subscriptions e.g. [Starter +feature 1(+10 $)], [Starter +feature 2(+10 $)], ect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe doesn't natively support add-ons. There are a number of third party tools that add this feature on top of Stripe, which can be useful if you're dealing with complicated up and downgrades with prorations.

Using just Stripe, standard practice would be to create a subscription with the plan (Starter, Plus, Premium), and then listen for the invoice.created webhook each month to add the necessary add-ons.

Answer (score 8):

On **Jan 30, 2017** Stripe released this functionality by supporting [multiple plans for a single subscription](https://stripe.com/blog/multiplan-subscriptions).

[More information](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/multiplan)

> Unlike our multiple subscriptions on a customer capability, which
>   generates an invoice for each subscription, putting multiple plans
>   into a single subscription results in a single invoice each billing
>   period that combines every subscription. Only a single payment for
>   that invoice is required, reducing your costs and the number of
>   charges your customer sees.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old link but how about setting up each add on as a separate subscription.

Multiple subscriptions can be attached to a user. https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/multiple-subscriptions.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with multiple subscriptions is that they are all invoiced separately. So in this instance, each add-on subscription would send the customer a single invoice. To mitigate this, you can prevent users from receiving invoices automatically, and build your own invoices with the data from Stripe.